# List Directories in Json File

Tags: php, json

I can list all the images from a folder in json using the code below:

```
<?php

$dir = "images/friday/";
$images = glob($dir."*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image){
  $registro = array(
    "FILE" => $image
  );
  $retorno[] = $registro;
}

$retorno = json_encode($retorno);
echo $retorno;

?>
```

I think it would work with directories too but nothing is displayed if I don´t use print_r($dirs).

```
<?php

  $path = "images";
  $dirs = glob($path . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

  foreach($dirs as $dir){
    $reg = array(
     "FOLDER" => $dir
     );

    $return[] = $reg;
  }

  $return = json_encode($return);
  echo $return;

?>
```

**echo $return** does not display anything. Is there a simple workaround or I have to build something like this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870159/list-files-on-directory-and-print-result-as-json)? I need the "FOLDER" identifier.

Comment: This code works fine. Are you sure you have folders in `images` and the path is correct?

Comment: @u_mulder The second code you mean, right? Yes, I am. Using print_r($dirs) it returns Array ( [0] => images/Friday [1] => images/Friday-Night [2] => images/Saturday )

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: @u_mulder I cannot echo the json in browser like I do with the first code: [{"FILE":"images\/Friday\/01.jpg"},{"FILE":"images\/Friday-Night\/02.jpg"},{"FILE":"images\/Saturday\/flyer01.jpg"}]

Comment: So `echo $return` outputs nothing?

Comment: @u_mulder No, like I said in question "...but nothing is displayed if I don´t use print_r()."

Comment: I don't understand. You use `echo` and see nothing, but when you use `print` - you see result? or what?

Comment: yes, only with print I see result

Comment: And what do you see with `var_dump($return)`? Sure you echo `$return` and not `$retorno`?

Comment: I get boolean false with var_dump($return)

Comment: Not sure what to do else. If `json_encode` gives you false, then some error happens. If your php is 5.5 and more you can use `json_last_error_msg` or `json_last_error` for php5.3.

Comment: Solved. I had some folders with accents. When I removed them it worked. Thanks man!